# How to directly print a pdf file in assets with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, printing, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I'm trying to print a pdf file using flutter app. I have used this Printing package to achieve this but the problem is it has this default page with options to save pdf and select printer. I don't want these options, I just want to print file in one click. How do I achieve this??

This is my code :

```
Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: 
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: ()async{
            final pdf =await rootBundle.load("assets/dummy.pdf");
            await Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (_) => pdf.buffer.asUint8List());
        }, child: const Text("PRINT")),
      ),
    );
```

[I want print pdf without showing this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJKfB.png)

Comment: I am not sure about this, but I don't think this is possible. It is up to the device what to do with your request to print something, and many Android Versions just happen to have a printing dialog like this. If you test it on e. g. Windows, you might see different results.

Comment: @Anjana Rodrigo , no..not yet